# ArcGIS JS API - Convert Lon,Lat to X,Y with custom SpatialReference

Tags: maps, gis, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to convert lon,lat values to X,Y coordinates to update the geometry on a feature. Currently, what I have, I believe should work, but doesn't:

```
var t = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(new esri.geometry.Point(lon,lat),   
        new esri.SpatialReference({ wkid: 32616 }));
console.log(t);
```

This returns:

```
Object {
    type: "point",
    x: 3864579.687523207,
    y: -22608299.977863092,
    spatialReference: { wkid: 102100 }
}

// the numbers for x,y should be something close to: 529000, 3842179
```

Even though I'm specifying the spatialReference to as `{ wkid: 32616 }`, it's returning with `{ wkid: 32616 }`.

How do I go about correctly converting lon,lat to x,y with a different spatialReference than the default 102100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Geometry Service to reproject the geometry into the new Spatial Reference.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html#project

Answer (score 1):

use the Geometry Service or  create your own service for this operation..
ArcGis Javascript api  does not have any solution for such issues